# Get DateTime from text

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to separate and display only the DateTime from the string?

I have a column that holds this data:

```
Comments
-----------------------------------------
Daniel reached the school by 9:25:00 alone
Breakfast was served by 10:17:27 in the morning
Reached back home late evening by 7:00:48
```

I used this query to separate out the time:

```
(CONVERT(varchar(max), Comments, 108)) [Comments],
```

and it returned the same lines. String didn't get filtered

When I tried using this statement:

```
(CONVERT(TIME, Comments, 108)) [Comments],
```

I got this error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

How can I overcome time and get the below expected result?

```
Comments
----------------------------------------
9:25:00 
10:17:27 
7:00:48
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With patindex you can locate the time pattern.

> ```
> select
> try_cast(substring(Comments, patindex('%[ 0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%', Comments), 8) as time(0)) CommentTime
> from your_table
> ```

> | CommentTime |
> | --- |
> | 09:25:00 |
> | 10:17:27 |
> | 07:00:48 |

Answer (score 3):

You can use `STRING_SPLIT` and `TRY_CONVERT`.

```
SELECT Tbl.Comments, T.value
FROM Tbl CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Tbl.Comments,' ') As T
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(TIME, value) IS NOT NULL
```

for versions that do not support `STRING_SPLIT`, the same logic can be implemented using `XML`, since there is already a solution using `PATINDEX`.

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT Comments, CONVERT(XML, CONCAT('<n>',REPLACE(Comments,' ','</n><n>'),'</n>')) AS x
FROM Tbl)
SELECT cte.Comments, v.value('.','varchar(MAX)')
FROM cte CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/n') AS t(v)
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(TIME, v.value('.','varchar(MAX)')) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @Austin I didn't notice this tag. I implemented the same logic without using STRING_SPLIT, but for the sake of interest.

Answer (score 0):

```
ltrim(substring(comments, charindex(comments, ':') - 2, 8))
```

Obviously this assumes there's always a colon and that the first colon is within the time element. It also assumes that all times have a leading space and are 7-8 characters in length. Depending on what you intend to do with this the `ltrim()` is probably unnecessary.

This is just string parsing. I realize this doesn't actually convert to a time value since it's not clear OP requires that in the output.